# How can I limit the size of uploaded files with PHP?

Tags: php, file, filesize, uploading

I want to limit the file size of images that can be uploaded to a remote server. I wrote the following code that does allow me to successfully upload files which work fine in my image gallery.

However, I want to limit the file size to about 2 MB. This code does work for uploading files, but it does not limit the file size. Furthermore, I thought that PHP has a built-in maximum upload file size. With this code, I can even upload a 31.4MB .mp4 file. Here is the code:

```
<?php 
$max = 2000 * 1024;
$message = '';
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $destination = __DIR__ . '/_images/';
    if ($_FILES['filename']['error'] == 0) {
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $destination 
            . $_FILES['filename']['name']);
        if ($result) {
            $message = $_FILES['filename']['name'] ;
        } else {
            $message = 'Sorry, there was a problem uploading ' 
                .$_FILES['filename']['name'];
        }
    } else {
        switch ($_FILES['filename']['error']) {
            case 2:
                $message = $_FILES['filename']['name'] . ' is too big to upload.';
                break;
            case 4:
                $message = 'No file selected.';
                break;
            default:
                $message = 'Sorry, there was a problem uploading ' 
                    .$_FILES['filename']['name'];
                break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 1) set limit in apache 2) set limit in php.ini 3) have your code check for exceeding the limit.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />` before the file input.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked: <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" /> .This is what the tutorial instructed:     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max; ?>"/> .

Comment: @AbraCadaver that is the worst possible option - any of the three things Marc suggested would be better. If you're going to use a solution that is set on the client-side, you're much better off using the File API to check the file size from your input element as soon as you choose the file. This way, you don't have to wait at all -- users will know as soon as they choose a file that it's too big. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications